# Check time range data..How?

Tags: java

how to get Time range data..

```
001:Sunday:08:00
002:Sunday:08:10
003:Sunday:08:15
004:Sunday:08:20
005:Sunday:09:20
006:Sunday:10:00
007:Sunday:13:00
```

for example i want to get 08:00 to 09:00 result

how to get it 
(data has been written in a text file)(String type data)

Comment: You should explain why `09:00` and/or what do you mean by "i want to get 08:00 to 09:00 result" (maybe post an example)

Comment: Your example is not clear

Comment: i need check and get data 08:00 to 09:00

Comment: First you write some code to read that text file. Then you write some code to search/filter what you need. If you have trouble at that point, *then* you post a question on here, including the code you've written, and a description of what problem you're having. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i want to select between from 08:00 09:00 data with in data range

Comment: I think the question is not that unclear... I understood that he/she needs to get rows (items) that have time in given input range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go this way using SimpleDateFormat:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE:HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
    // you can read from, to, filePath from args

    Date from = DATE_FORMAT.parse("Sunday:08:00");
    Date to = DATE_FORMAT.parse("Sunday:09:00");

    Collection<Item> items = readItems(new File("pathToInputFile"));
    Collection<Item> filtered = filterItems(items, from, to);
    // do something with your filtered items
}

public static Collection<Item> readItems(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

    Collection<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String[] split = scanner.next().split(":");
        if (split.length < 4) {
            continue; // incomplete row, skip or maybe throw exception?
        }
        Date date = DATE_FORMAT.parse(split[1] + ":" + split[2] + ":" + split[3])
        items.add(new Item(split[0], date));
    }
    return items;
}


// This is for Java 7, if you are using Java 8+, you can use lambdas for filtering
public static Collection<Item> filterItems(Collection<Item> items, Date from, Date to) {
    Collection<Item> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        long millis = item.getDate().getTime();
        if (millis >= from.getTime() && millis <= to.getTime()) {
            filtered.add(item);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Simple Item class:

```
public class Item {

    private final String id;
    private final Date date;

    public Item(String id, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```